# Design pattern for alternate action if app in foreground?

Tags: android, intentservice

I'm building an action which utilizes Google Cloud Messaging for receiving push notifications.

This involves a couple notable components, namely:

- A `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` to receive the message from GCM.
- An `IntentService` to be notified when a GCM event is received.

As I'm sure is the case for many applications, I'd like to take a different approach for when the application has an activity in the foreground vs. when the application does *not* have an application in the foreground.

I'd like to post a notification to the notification drawer if the application is not active, and simply forward the event onto the foreground activity if the application is active.

Is there a design pattern for this? How should I go about determining if the app is in the foreground vs. the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow an approach as outlined in [this blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html) where you create a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Activity` with a positive priority (i.e., higher than the default of `0`) which intercepts a specific action and then calls `abortBroadcast` - this handles the app open case. You then also register a `BroadcastReceiver` in your Manifest which handles the same action but at the default priority - this is the fallback if the app is not open and it creates the system notification.

You then use `sendOrderedBroadcast()` to send your broadcast to all registered receivers in priority order. If the activity is open, the first will handle it. Otherwise, it will default to the other one and create a notification.

Comment: Excellent solution, seems the most straightforward way according to what Android has to offer.

Answer (score 2):

The way I suggest doing it is as following.

Have all the logic regarding GCM in a Service (I've never used `IntentService`, so I don't know about it's guts, but I see it inherits from `Service`).

In your activity, you probably have a way of starting the service (perhaps the user activates through a button), nothing new here.

Here comes the fun part. In your activity you handle `onPause()` and `onResume()`. In `onResume()` you **bind** to the service. With the binding mechanism you can get a pointer to your service and let it know that you're there "*hey service, I'm an activity and I'm here... please store a pointer to myself somewhere*", and the service stores a pointer to the activity (let's call it `mActivity`). In your `onPause()` you notify the service that you're leaving, so the service sets `mActivity = null`, and then you **unbind** from the service.

With this mechanism, every time the Service receives a push notification, it tests the `mActivity` variable to see if there's a bound Activity. With a pointer to your Activity you can invoke any of it's methods, forward information...