# Checking by code whether android app is foreground or background on device

Tags: android, push-notification, app-startup

I wants to determine whether my app is in **foreground or background** on device.
In my app, When i get push notification on device then it is require to me that identify 1. whether app is in background or foreground? 2. What is/was the current/last opened activity of app.

and **one more thing**, I also wants to find out the check box value(checked/unchecked) of "**show notifications**" checkbox of app setting(find it by going setting->app manager->select my app from list). According to the value of this checkbox, different code will execute in my app.

Yours help is appreciated,

Thanking you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Design pattern for alternate action if app in foreground?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001844/design-pattern-for-alternate-action-if-app-in-foreground)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method onwindowFocusChanged() to determine whether your window (activity) gained (foreground) or lost (background) focus. This is the function:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

//write your code here

}
```

You can add this to your activities

Answer (score 0):

public boolean IsAppForeground(Context context){

ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (appProcesses == null){
      return false;
    }
    final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses)
 {
  if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) 
    {
        return true;
      }
    }return false;
  }